# Servlets-JSP: How to put a delete-modify button for every row of HTML table!

Tags: servlets

I'm trying to add to every row of a HTML table a "delete" and a "modify" button.
If I use this method, the value of the "id" is alawys the value of id from the first row, even if I pressed the button from the rows 2-n.

```
<%  if (listx.size() > 0)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listx.size(); i++)
        {
            Contact x= listx.get(i);
%>
<form action="servl" method="get">
    <tr>
        <td><%=++j%>            </td>
        <td><%=x.getName()%>            </td>
        <td><%=x.getCar()%>            </td>
        <td><%=x.getZip()%>            </td>

        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<%=x.getId()%>">
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="modify">
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="delete"</td>
    </tr>
<%
    } %>
```

P.S. 1. This could be a solution: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/post983361.html#post983361 (post 10) but I need that my inputs to be in this format:

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="NameOfTheAction">
```

Later Edit: Don't say anything about the scriplets. I will use JSTL later. :)

***Problem solved***:  I found out the problem. I didn't closed the form tag for every row. I closed the tag only at the finish of the table (creating a form for the whole table), so every time I pressed a row button, every "id" was send.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Contact` is assigned to `x` but you're using `contact` in your hidden "ID".  Also, why the need for the extra `j` variable... couldn't you just use `(i + 1)`?

**EDIT:**

I see you sneakily updated your code to correct the variable problem.  Are you still having issues?  Some obvious questions... Does each of your contacts *have* an ID, and is `getId()` returning the correct value if you loop through them outside of the JSP?

Comment: 1. Yes, you're rite, I changed the name of the variabiles a little, because they're in a another language.

2. Probably, but this not my problem now. :)

Comment: Yes, I sneakly updated the code. :)) 

2. Yes, every contact has his own id. I used "Page source" from Firefox and every row has his own unique id. 

If I use the "get" method (HTML),the URL is something like this: ID=1&ID=2&action=modify&ID=3&ID=4&ID=5

Comment: Oh, I see.  Because you have a hidden input element for every row, it's sending all of the values to the server.

Comment: I found out the problem. 
I didn't closed the form tag for every row.
I close the tag only at the finish of the table, so every time I pressed a row button, every "id" was send.